# Conditional Expectation for independent sigma-algebras

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, independence

Let $X,Y,Z$ be random variables such that $\sigma(X,Y)$ is independent of $Z$.

How can I prove that for any measurable $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ we have:
$$E[\mathbb{1}_{A}(X)|\sigma(Y,Z)] = E[\mathbb{1}_{A}(X)|\sigma(Y)]$$

This seems clear intuitively, but I have failed to find a formal proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\sigma(Y,Z)$ is generated by $\{A\cap B: A\in\sigma(Y),B\in\sigma(Z)\}$. Also for any $A\in\sigma(Y)$ and $B\in\sigma(Z)$ one has
$$
\mathsf{E}[f(X) 1_{A\cap B}]=\mathsf{E}[f(X) 1_A] \mathsf{P}(B) 
=\mathsf{E}[\mathsf{E}[f(X)\mid \sigma(Y)] 1_{A\cap B}],
$$
where $f$ is any suitable function.

Comment: Maybe I should add for future reference that we need Dynkins Lemma in between. But great short answer, I simply did not notice how $\sigma(Y,Z)$ can be generated